# What is the approach to solving this first order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What method should I use to solve this first order nonlinear differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(ax+by)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+vy}{(cx+gy)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+vx}$$

The constants here are $a,b,c,g,v$. I can't reduce it to linear ODE, nor seperate it. I have also tried using the exact differential form, but it doesn't work. What methods can be used to solve this ODE, or is this ODE unsolvable analytically?

Comment: To avoid closing, show some of your efforts at solving.

Comment: Mathematica and Maple both can not solve it. This is very good indication this has no analytical solution. Try either series solution or numerical solution.